# R sf polygon only showing 3 corners

Tags: r, polygon, sf

I'm trying to make a polygon over a chunk of North America.

I try to make this 4 cornered polygon

```
NAbounds<-st_multipoint(c(st_point(c(-103.58,28.9)), #SW
                          st_point(c(-67.76,47.19)), #NE
                          st_point(c(-114.33,49.06)), #NW
                          st_point(c(-85.56,30.4)) #SE
                        ))  %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_sfc(crs='+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84') %>% st_sf()
```

When I do

```
mapdeck(style = mapdeck_style('light'), 
        zoom = 4,
        location = c(-89.90, 39.51)) %>% add_polygon(NAbounds)
```

I get a triangle:

[image]

If I rearrange the points then it makes a triangle out of the first 3 points that I feed it.  How do I make the 4 cornered polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I reordered the points so that they're in a path and that produced what I expected...

```
NAbounds<-st_multipoint(c(st_point(c(-103.58,28.9)), #SW
                          st_point(c(-114.33,49.06)), #NW
                          st_point(c(-67.76,47.19)), #NE
                          st_point(c(-85.56,30.4)) #SE

                        ))  %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_sfc(crs='+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84') %>% st_sf()

mapdeck(style = mapdeck_style('light'), 
        zoom = 4,
        location = c(-89.90, 39.51)) %>% add_polygon(NAbounds)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the code in the question created a "bow-tie" polygon with a self-intersection, and if you test it with `st_is_valid(NAbounds)` it returns `FALSE` because those aren't allowed in Simple Features polygons.